# Sign In With popup in AngularFire Auth Ionic Mobile

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I have a Ionic mobile app, in which I want to implement Google Sign In with Firebase.

As I am using Angular, I choose this library: https://github.com/angular/angularfire

Unfortunately, I am facing a problem.
When I click the button to join with google, the browser opens, at the Firebase project name's url, then it redirects the page on chrome to `localhost/{page-name}`. I want it to redirect it to my Ionic App.

My Code:

I have added the required libraries in the app.module.ts file:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    ...,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireAuthModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ...,
    OauthService,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I have defined OauthService as follows:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { auth } from 'firebase/app';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OauthService {
  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
  ) { }

  joinWithGoogle() {
    const provider = new auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    const scope = ["profile", "email"];
    return this.socialSignIn(provider.providerId, scope);
  }

  private socialSignIn(providerName: string, scopes?: Array<string>): Promise<any> {
    const provider = new auth.OAuthProvider(providerName);
    if (scopes) {
      scopes.forEach(scope => {
        provider.addScope(scope);
      })
    }
    return this.afAuth.signInWithPopup(provider);
  }

  returnAuthState() {
    return this.afAuth.authState;
  }
}
```

Then I call OauthService.joinWithGoogle() like this:

```js
this.oauthService.joinWithGoogle().then(() => {
  console.log("DONE!");
  const authListner = this.oauthService.returnAuthState().subscribe(user => {
    if (user) {
      console.log("Yay!!!");
      console.log(user);       
    } else {
      console.log(":(");
    }
    authListner.unsubscribe();
  })
})
```

NOTE: I have tried Sign In with Popup and Sign In with Redirect

Can anybody point where I am wrong?
Thanks